# Determine month before date - Python

Tags: python, datetime, time

In python, how can I determine the month before the following date:

```
t = datetime.date(2014, 01, 03)
```

This is so that the result would be:

```
2013-12-03
```

Comment: So what is the expected result for `datetime.date(2014, 3, 31)`?

Comment: Your example subtracts a full year, not a month.

Comment: @MarkRansom Subtracting a month, which is January, should return the month December which is in the previous year

Comment: @NorthernStars: look closely at your last edit then.

Comment: Pro tip: don't put leading zeros on your numbers. In Python 2 you might not get the number you expect, and in Python 3 it's a syntax error.

Comment: @MarkRansom: `08`, `09` would produce `SyntaxError` even on Python 2 otherwise two-digit numbers are safe here (though non-portable to Python 3).

Comment: do you want to find a previous month or the month that corresponds to yesterday?

Answer (score 1):

To find the previous month relative to a given date:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import date, timedelta

t = date(2014, 1, 3)
print(t.replace(day=1) - timedelta(1)) # the last day of the previous month
# -> 2013-12-31
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import dateutil.relativedelta
t - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the date yesterday:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
date1 = date(2014, 1, 3)
date2 = date1 - timedelta(days=1)
print date2.strftime('%y, %m, %d')
```

If you want to know the date 1 month before:

```
from datetime import timedelta, date
def subtract_one_month(dt0):
    dt1 = dt0.replace(days=1)
    dt2 = dt1 - timedelta(days=1)
    dt3 = dt2.replace(days=1)
    return dt3

date1 = date(2014, 1, 3)
date2 = subtract_one_month(date1)
print date2.strftime('%y, %m, %d')
```

Comment: it finds a day before today (*yesterday*). It is hard to understand what OP wants. I've interpreted it as: OP wants [the previous *month*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29480880/4279). Unrelated: you have issues with names: `datetime`, `date` in your code (fix the import, use a different name for the variable).

Answer (score 0):

What you could do instead is have separate variables for each measure of time, year, month, and day. Then, you could use an if statement that makes it so when the month is 1, the year goes back 1 and the month is set to 12. Lastly, just plug those numbers into the parentheses and you're all set!

```python
year = 2014
month = 1
day = 3
if month == 1:
    year -= 1
    month = 12

else:
    month -= 1

t = date.datetime(year, month, date)
```

Comment: it won't work because tuples are immutable, because you can't use the same name to mean different thing in the same scope at the same time in Python. It won't work for any month except January. There is no `0` day in a month (days start with `1`).

Comment: He only wants it so it changes when it's January... Right?